# The method '[]' was called on null. Receiver: null Tried calling: []("displayName")

Tags: firebase, flutter

This error is caused by what? The other files have the same code format, but there are no errors.

I use displayName as the document name.

**Error**

The method '[]' was called on null.

Receiver: null

Tried calling: [] ("displayName")

```
final DocumentSnapshot data;

    body: StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
              stream: Firestore.instance
                  .collection('users')
                  .document(widget.data['displayName'])
                  .collection('chat')
                  .snapshots(),
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                if (!snapshot.hasData) return LinearProgressIndicator();
                return Container();
              })
```

**DB :**

```
static Future<void> sendChatToFirebase(
    String chatID,
    String chatContent,
    FirebaseUser currentUser,
    DocumentSnapshot data
  ) async {
    Firestore.instance
    .collection('users')
    .document(data.documentID)
    .collection('chat')
    .document(chatID)
    .setData({
      'chatID': chatID,
      'chatTimeStamp': DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch,
      'chatContent': chatContent,
      'displayName': currentUser.displayName,
      'photoUrl': currentUser.photoUrl,
    });
  }
```

Comment: Can you show in the code how you're passing the data to this widget; and I'll assume this is a StatefulWidget since you're doing **widget.data** and passing the data as a dictionary); also I noticed you're doing **Firestore.instance.collection('users').document()**; it should be **Firestore.instance.collection('users').doc()**.

Comment: I have updated the code

Comment: Still I need to see how you’re passing the **data** into the widget. I believe that’s where the problem lies. Are you passing it via the constructor when this widget is instantiated / mounted on the widget tree?

Answer (score 0):

The error message means, that you are trying to access ['displayName'] from a null value. Somehow your widget.data is null.

It's basically the same as calling
***null['displayName']***

```
Map<String, dynamic> test; // NULL, but expected as Map / Json / {}

print(test["displayName"]); // throws an error, because what was actually called is null["displayName"]
```

Comment: In other files I use similar code but no errors.

Comment: You can debug or simply put the print statements in your code before StreamBuilder to check what value does widget.data has

Answer (score 0):

The index [] operator on the Map class returns null if the key isn’t present. This implies that the return type of that operator must be nullable.
See [null safety](https://dart.dev/null-safety/understanding-null-safety#the-map-index-operator-is-nullable). This means that your
`widget.data['displayName']`
may return `null`.
To fix your issue you need to check that `widget.data['displayName]` is not null, if so then you can use the `!` to say that `widget.data['displayName]` is not null.

```
widget.data['displayName']!
```